Unexpected SSH disconnections and system freezes on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
System Information
Kernel: 6.5.0-41-generic
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

Issue Description
I am experiencing a strange issue with my Ubuntu desktop computer, which I use as a server and access remotely from a Windows machine via SSH. The problem occurs around 3-4 AM when the connection drops, and I can no longer access the server or any hosted webpages. The screen is visible but completely frozen, and the time displayed does not match the disconnection time. Despite the computer being unresponsive, the case indicators and fans continue to run. I've been tracking this problem for some time.
To verify if it’s merely a network interface issue (though it's odd that a network failure would freeze the display), I wrote a Python script that logs the current time every second. This allows me to monitor whether the computer is still running.
I initially thought the disconnection time would match when the system stopped, but strangely, the last logged time from the script is several hours after the disconnection and just minutes before I manually rebooted the computer.
Timeline
Disconnection Time: 2024-07-16 04:47:55
Last Logged Time by Script: 2024-07-16 08:21:53
Manual Reboot Time: 2024-07-16 08:50:18
journalctl Logs
From 4 AM to 8 AM, the logs show the following:
Jul 16 04:17:01 bachelor-ubuntu CRON[22723]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Jul 16 04:17:01 bachelor-ubuntu CRON[22724]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 16 04:17:01 bachelor-ubuntu CRON[22723]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 16 04:18:47 bachelor-ubuntu snapd[1126]: storehelpers.go:923: cannot refresh: snap has no updates available: "bare", "core22", "firefox", "gnome-42-2204", "gtk-common-themes", "rclone", "snap-store", "snapd", "snapd-desktop-integration"
Jul 16 08:12:04 bachelor-ubuntu kernel: rcu: INFO: rcu_preempt self-detected stall on CPU
Jul 16 08:12:04 bachelor-ubuntu kernel: rcu:         27-...!: (1 GPs behind) idle=791c/1/0x4000000000000002 softirq=623018/623018 fqs=0
Jul 16 08:12:04 bachelor-ubuntu kernel: rcu:         (t=549756 jiffies g=4599397 q=56 ncpus=48)
Jul 16 08:12:04 bachelor-ubuntu kernel: rcu: rcu_preempt kthread timer wakeup didn't happen for 549755 jiffies! g4599397 f0x0 RCU_GP_WAIT_FQS(5) ->state=0x402
Jul 16 08:12:04 bachelor-ubuntu kernel: rcu:         Possible timer handling issue on cpu=7 timer-softirq=122527
Jul 16 08:12:04 bachelor-ubuntu kernel: rcu: rcu_preempt kthread starved for 549756 jiffies! g4599397 f0x0 RCU_GP_WAIT_FQS(5) ->state=0x402 ->cpu=7
Jul 16 08:12:04 bachelor-ubuntu kernel: rcu:         Unless rcu_preempt kthread gets sufficient CPU time, OOM is now expected behavior.
Jul 16 08:12:04 bachelor-ubuntu kernel: rcu: RCU grace-period kthread stack dump:
Jul 16 08:12:04 bachelor-ubuntu kernel: task:rcu_preempt     state:I stack:0     pid:16    ppid:2      flags:0x00004000

Crash Files
The timestamps of files in /var/crash/ do not match the system freeze time:
-rw-r-----  1 bachelor         whoopsie 62415059 Jul 15 00:23 _opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root             whoopsie  4525379 Jul 15 10:30 _usr_bin_udevadm.0.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root             whoopsie   333191 Jul 16 09:25 _usr_libexec_boltd.0.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root             whoopsie  4397017 Jul 16 09:25 _usr_lib_systemd_systemd-journald.0.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root             whoopsie   370893 Jul 15 07:43 _usr_lib_systemd_systemd-logind.0.crash
-rw-r-----  1 systemd-timesync whoopsie   262137 Jul 15 04:32 _usr_lib_systemd_systemd-timesyncd.103.crash

Clearly, the crashes on the 16th occurred after I rebooted.
Request for Assistance
This issue occurs frequently around early morning hours, making it hard to address immediately. Although it has also happened once around noon when I was away from the computer. According to psensor, the temperature of the computer is normal, ruling out overheating.
Could you please help me identify the root cause of this issue?
journalctl from 1AM: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pqv2tgFZXN/
my hardware info: https://pastebin.com/mUcSRmP0
